# JavaScript written only with brackets?

Tags: javascript, xss

I once saw JavaScript code which was only written as multiple brackets `()`. Does anybody remember this kind of code? There was also an online converter to convert "normal" JS into this style of code. I want to show it while [a presentation](https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=dc439gz7_154f2zsg7f5) as an example of state of the art XSS. Or what are other really surprising XSS examples?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is only a XSS vulnerability if your site executes javascript code that could be provided by untrusted users and your only safeguard is blacklisting certain keywords (which is the wrong solution).  You should always use a whitelist policy/safer markup language that prevents users from executing javascript code (e.g., in comments they can't insert `<script>` tags, add `onclick/onhover`-type methods to html tags, or use `eval` on user provided input in your js, etc.).  Then this just is obsfuscation.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found it

- http://sla.ckers.org/forum/read.php?24,33349
- [http://security.bleurgh.net/javascript-without-letters-or-numbers](https://web.archive.org/web/20130111073815/http://security.bleurgh.net/javascript-without-letters-or-numbers)
- http://sla.ckers.org/forum/read.php?24,28687

Converter to convert normal JS into brackets only JS:

- http://utf-8.jp/public/jjencode.html

Comment: wow I didn't even think that was possible! time to modify my code filters! (and the next time somebody asks for an obfuscated program on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com I'll use this :)

Comment: Wow. I'll confess, when I read your question, I thought, "Man, this guy really doesn't know what the hell he's talking about." (I've been writing JavaScript for years.) Now, seeing this? Head asplode.

Answer (score 7):

This is an interesting find!

**To those who are only just now finding out...**

It is now obvious how you can create strings out of braces, and you could do things like `window[gibberish](gibberish)` to eval something. What may not be clear is that you can do this without the word `window`. All you need is a variable name (like `$` or `_`)

Run this prep code

```
$=~[];$={___:++$,$$$$:(![]+"")[$],__$:++$,$_$_:(![]+"")[$],_$_:++$,$_$$:({}+"")[$],$$_$:($[$]+"")[$],_$$:++$,$$$_:(!""+"")[$],$__:++$,$_$:++$,$$__:({}+"")[$],$$_:++$,$$$:++$,$___:++$,$__$:++$};$.$_=($.$_=$+"")[$.$_$]+($._$=$.$_[$.__$])+($.$$=($.$+"")[$.__$])+((!$)+"")[$._$$]+($.__=$.$_[$.$$_])+($.$=(!""+"")[$.__$])+($._=(!""+"")[$._$_])+$.$_[$.$_$]+$.__+$._$+$.$;$.$$=$.$+(!""+"")[$._$$]+$.__+$._+$.$+$.$$;$.$=($.___)[$.$_][$.$_]
```

You will have a function.

Run this to call `alert(0)` on that function

```
$.$($.$($.$$+"\""+$.$_$_+(![]+"")[$._$_]+$.$$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+$.__+"("+$.___+")"+"\"")())();
```

[Source](http://utf-8.jp/public/jjencode.html)